# Is there a cleaner way to rerun an api call than using window.setInterval() than I am doing here?

Tags: javascript, rest, setinterval

I'm not very familiar with javascript or programming at all for that matter. However although, I did managed to accomplish the difficult task for me. I am wondering, Is there a proper or more pragmatic way of doing this? Thank you in advance for your help. This is for a queue management system if anyone was wondering.

```js
var requestURL = 'https://api.qminder.com/v1/tickets/search/?rest-api-key=APIKEY'
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
  var customers = request.response;
  console.log(customers.data)

  x = []

  for (var i = 0; i < customers.data.length; i++) {

    console.log(customers.data[i].status);

    if (customers.data[i].status == "NEW") {
      x.push(customers.data[i])
    }
  }

  var html = '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + x[i].firstName + '</li>';
    console.log(x[i].firstName)
  }
  html += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = html;

}


window.setInterval(function() {
  var requestURL = 'https://api.qminder.com/v1/tickets/search/?rest-api-key=APIKEY'
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    var customers = request.response;
    console.log(customers.data)

    x = []

    for (var i = 0; i < customers.data.length; i++) {

      console.log(customers.data[i].status);

      if (customers.data[i].status == "NEW") {
        x.push(customers.data[i])
      }
    }

    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      html += '<li>' + x[i].firstName + '</li>';
      console.log(x[i].firstName)
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = html;

  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: you can use setTimeout and setInterval to achieve regular calls at specific interval. I do not think, there is any other method. Though, you can use jQuery to shorten and beautify the code so that it becomes easy to handle later on.

Comment: If you do not want setInterval() ( which is the easiest way to do this kind of 'polling' afaik ) , you can also set up a socket connection between the server and the website so that the server can notify the website when there's a new ticket. ( push messages )  But that will be harder to create. Using fetch() instead of xmlhttprequest could also shorten the code alot. Concerning JQuery, that's purely subjective. It can help writing shorter code, but it also taught me some bad practices I had to unlearn after.

Comment: Yes there is -- this is pretty ugly. First of all you are repeating yourself with the same large block of code -- why? Second, why are you doing something every 2 seconds irrespective of results?

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments. As for why I did it this way @amn I did this in an 8 hour learning sprint with not very much practice or experience.

Comment: @Kelbizzle Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case DRY - Don't repeat yourself

```js
function requestIt() {
  var requestURL = 'https://api.qminder.com/v1/tickets/search/?rest-api-key=APIKEY'
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.onload = function() {
    var customers = request.response;
    console.log(customers.data)

    x = []

    for (var i = 0; i < customers.data.length; i++) {

      console.log(customers.data[i].status);

      if (customers.data[i].status == "NEW") {
        x.push(customers.data[i])
      }
    }

    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      html += '<li>' + x[i].firstName + '</li>';
      console.log(x[i].firstName)
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = html;

  }
  request.send(); // do not send before the onload has been defined
}
requestIt(); // first call
window.setInterval(requestIt, 2000);
```

However I would prefer installing jQuery just for this and NOT use interval in case the server blocks

```js
var requestURL = 'https://api.qminder.com/v1/tickets/search/?rest-api-key=APIKEY'

function requestIt() {
  $.get(requestURL, customers => {
    console.log(customers.data);
    var html = ['<ul>'];
    customers.data.filter(data => data.status == "NEW")
      .forEach(x => html.push('<li>' + x.firstName + '</li>'))
    )
    html.push('</ul>')
    $("#names").html(html.join(""));
    setTimeout(requestIt,2000);
  })
}  
requestIt();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have given me a lot to improve on. And I agree I will need to read into and practice the DRY paradigm a bit deeper. I really appreciate it. Thank you for you help.

Comment: YW. Note I had a stray [i] in the `x => html.push('<li>' + x.firstName + '</li>')`

Comment: No worries. I did catch that. Thank you again for your help. I hope to teach it to someone else some day.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function in a row, using `setTimeout` and waiting for the request to finish

```
var timeoutPtr;

/**
 * Execute a request, can take DELTA miliseconds
 */
function executeRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // ...

    request.onload = function() {
      // ...

      resolve();
    };

    request.send();
  });
}

/**
 * Execute the request, when it's over, wait 2s and execute it again
 * and again, and again...
 */
function executeRequestInARow() {
  // In case you call executeRequestInRow multiple time
  clearTimeout(timeoutPtr);

  executeRequest()
    .then(() => {
      timeoutPtr = setTimeout(function() {
        executeRequestInARow();
      }, 2000);
    });
}

executeRequestInARow();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate the time you took to help me.

Comment: Your answer is best suitable here and efficient, Thanks